# Django Virtual-Env Openid Import Error

Tags: python, django

I am getting this error while running the **Django** server from my virtual env (after installing **python-social-auth** )

```
 File "/var/www/virtualenv-12.0.4/mapfied/python-social-auth/social/storage/base.py", line 12, in <module>
    from openid.association import Association as OpenIdAssociation
ImportError: No module named 'openid'
```

Despite of having openid installed in my VirtualEnv,

```
sudo -H pip install django-openid-auth

Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): django-openid-auth in /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages
```

Anyone having this issue ? any fixes

Comment: Did you add it into your `INSTALLED_APP` tuple?

Comment: yup @dan-klasson ...wait you mean "social.apps.django_app.default" in app tuple ?

Comment: Yeah, did you add that in?

Comment: Yup already added ... but starting the django server giving me this error..

Comment: Doesn't look like you ran that pip install command into your virtualenv. Also if you did you should not need to use sudo.

Comment: ohh I ran inside the virtual env... added sudo with -H for suppressing errorsof log files permission

Comment: Says "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages".

Comment: Ooops I ran pip install django-openid-auth this inside my virtual env ..So what can I do now .. how to install it correctly

Comment: That's what you're supposed to do. But your command output says you didn't.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74929/discussion-between-anirban-n-and-dan-klasson).

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
pip install python-openid
```